# Utility to change password of ZIP compressed & encyrpted files

Tags: windows, file-management, encryption, file-compression, zip

Please recommend a gratis Windows tool that will allow me to change the password of existing ZIP compressed archive files.

I don't need a "cracking" tool.  I know the existing password.  I just need to quickly change the password of many ZIP files to a different password.

Ideally, the tool will just perform the operation in RAM, as the system that will process the task has much more RAM than the total uncompressed size of any of the ZIP archives.

Open-source would be great, but not required.

Comment: Related, not an answer: https://superuser.com/q/1310952

Comment: @Damien Very much related, thank you! The challenge will be to find software that does the "decrypt then encrypt" process automatically in RAM.

Comment: In case you don't find a fitting program: I am reasonably sure this is not overly difficult to program. In any case, yes it will involve reading the old file and creating a new file. See for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587561/password-protected-zip-file-in-java